# How inaccurate is QueryResult's underestimatedCount?

Tags: swift, sequence, realitykit

I am trying to write a System that removes entities from a scene when there are more than X of them. Can I rely on this `underestimatedCount` that I assume is faster or is casting to Array to get an accurate count fine?

```
    let entities = context.scene.performQuery(Self.query)
    let underestimatedCount = entities.underestimatedCount
    let accurateCount = Array(entities).count
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer, but I'll add: this isn't merely _casting_ to an Array. The your `entities` object (which has type `QueryResult`) is a `Sequence` (but not a `Collection`, hence no `count`). Most likely, it's a wrapper for a not-yet-calculated result for a query that'll be performed lazily. When you call `Array(entities)`, it's internally iterating over `entities` with a `for` loop and recording the elements.